# How do you evaluate a summation with variables in the parameters?

Tags: summation

my problem is

$\sum_{i=n+1}^{3n} (2i-3)$

I have done a few summations in calc 2, but I do not remember what you are supposed to do when there are variables in both parameters.

I remember the rules that
$i = \frac{(n^2+n)}{2} $
but Im not sure if that applies here

edit: adjusted the denominator which I had incorrect

Comment: If you know $$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n^2+n}{2}$$ (I fixed the denominator), see if you can write this problem in terms of that.  Mainly, it tests you understanding of the $\sum$ symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{i=n+1}^{3n} (2i-3) = \sum_{i=1}^{3n} (2i-3) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-3)$$
Can you take it from here?

You will have to use the fact that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

For the sake of completeness, here is the full solution:

\begin{align*}\sum_{i=n+1}^{3n} (2i-3) = \sum_{i=1}^{3n} (2i-3) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-3)&=2\sum_{i=1}^{3n}i-9n-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}i+3n \\
&=3n(3n+1)-9n-n(n+1)+3n \\
&=8n^2-4n
\end{align*}

Comment: yes I believe I would split them up then make the change but...does the 3 from the 3n at the top just get multiplied to the whole thing?

Comment: The $3n$ on top merely means that the upper limit of the dummy variable $i$ is $3n$.

Comment: do we insert that anywhere? or is that not necessary

Comment: I have edited my answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes perfect sense thank you so much

Comment: You are most welcome :)